# Addition of unsigned long and int in C

Tags: c, hex, unsigned-integer

```
    int meta_size = 24;
    node_t* prev;

    printf("%lx, ", prev + meta_size );
    printf("%lx, ", prev); 
    printf("%lx, ", meta_size);
```

out put: 1519240, 1519000, 18
how this is happening?

Comment: What did you expect? You are using the wrong format specifier to print a pointer, which invokes undefined baheviour. And despite your title, you don't add a `unsigned long` and an `int`.

Comment: Do you understand [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prev is a unitialised pointer, it contains (a random, because it is not initialised) memory address.

```
printf("%lx, ", prev + meta_size );//Prints the memory address prev is pointing to + (sizeof(node_t) * meta_size)
printf("%lx, ", prev);             //Prints the memory address prev is pointing to
printf("%lx, ", meta_size);        //Prints meta_size, 18 is 24 in hexidecimal, because of the 'x' in %lx
```

However, the first 2 lines are undefined behaviour because pointers should be printed with %p

Comment: prev is initialized. I just didn't show it.

Answer (score 0):

if you do `sizeof(node_t)` I'm pretty sure you will obtain 10.

Comment: Actually `24` decimal or `0x18` hex. Note that all of the output numbers are hex.

Comment: yes you are right. When you add n to a node_t pointer, the pointer address will be increase by n * (sizeof(node_t)) thats why it is increase by 240 in base 16 = 576 in base 10 = 24 * 24 in base 10.